# How to add a row to a table using sqlite browser in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I was able to delete rows in the table i have created by simply clicking on the button "Delete Record". But when i am trying to add a row by clicking on the button "New Record", it displayed an error like this [image]

so, in the preferences i have set the default value to empty string. Still it is not working and is displaying the same error. Is it possible to add like this or not? And when i create a new table, there is no problem in creating a new record. But how to add data into that row? please help me. Thank you

Comment: did you do what it says?

Comment: What is the table definition? Can you show the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement,name text primary key, email text); This is the statement. But when i am exporting the database to a SQL file from the sqlite broswer, there in the file, the above statement is being modified and "NOT NULL" is being added instead of primary key

Answer (score 2):

According to this bug report:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2936194&group_id=87946&atid=584909

...this appears to be caused by a bug in the app which still isn't fixed (see comments on issue).

The last comment states they were successful in changing their preferences by creating a few registry keys where the app looks for its settings.